# Why is my logo shifting when it's in a smaller window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When I'm resizing my window to be smaller why is my logo shifting to the right instead of sticking close to the collapse icon.

CODEPLY: https://www.codeply.com/go/jXwAJWRAL5

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" style="background-color: black">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png" width="300" height="60"></a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Leaderboard</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 elements, a hidden burger nav, a logo and some menu items.
When it turns responsive it shows the burger nav and hides the menu items making it `burger nav` | `logo` instead of `logo` | `menu items`.

You should make it `logo` | `Burger Nav` | `Menu Items` so when they get shown and hidden they just take up the space the other one left behind. It's as simple as moving `<button>` underneath the `<a>` tag.

[image]

Comment: But once I do that the burger nav is now to the right instead of to the left.

Comment: Your `navbar` class has a flexbox style `space-between` which obviously means create space between these 2 objects. Ignore my first comment and just change that value to `flex-start` to make the elements just order from left to right.

Comment: so I would add ```flex-start``` to my nav class

Comment: On you `.navbar` class yes.